# IE6 and IE7 absolute positioned div on top of multiple relative divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to make multiple absolute-positioned divs overlap multiple relative-positioned divs in IE6 & IE7?

See this jsFiddle for more information: **http://jsfiddle.net/btker/1/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="relative_div">Relative div.
        <div class="absolute_div">This div have absolute position and is placed in a relative positioned div. This div should always be on top of all relative divs.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="relative_div">Relative div.
        <div class="absolute_div">This div have absolute position and is placed in a relative positioned div. This div should always be on top of all relative divs.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.relative_div {
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.absolute_div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

There are two relative `<div>`s (placed in identical wrappers) containing each one a absolute `<div>` that overlap all the relative `<div>`s. This works great without any problems in updated versions of Chrome, Firefox etc, the absolute `<div>` with `z-index` is always placed on top.

In IE6 and IE7 this is not working. The different between this problem and the standard "dropdown in header display its menus behind the page content" is that in those situations its often fixed by give the parent element of that specific menu other z-index etc. In this case the both absolute `<div>`s are put in identical `<div>`s.

Can this be solved so the absolute `<div>`s are always on top of all relative `<div>`s in IE6 & IE7? Conditional comments for IE can be used to make the solution cross-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but only by decreasing the `z-index` of the second `.wrapper` or increasing the `z-index` of the first `.wrapper`.

On a simple level, each positioned element with a non-auto `z-index` creates a new stacking context, although there are other circumstances in which a new stacking context is created - see [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

The problem is one that affects `IE <= 7`, from [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

> In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore `z-index` doesn't work correctly.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.lower {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.higher {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.relative_div {
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    position: relative;

}
.absolute_div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- add higher class here -->
  <div class="relative_div">Relative div.
      <div class="absolute_div">This div have absolute position and is placed in a relative positioned div. This div should always be on top of all relative divs.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- or add lower class here -->
  <div class="relative_div">Relative div.
      <div class="absolute_div">This div have absolute position and is placed in a relative positioned div. This div should always be on top of all relative divs.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figure this was the answer. Thank you for clarification.